# define set implementation type for list to set mapping

Tags: java, collections, dozer

I have a bidirectional list to set mapping in dozer and I was wondering whether it is possible to define the set implementation type, e.g. LinkedHashSet, that is utilised to create a new instance of the set. I tried the create-method attribute at this mapping. however, this method will be applied for item instantiation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a workaround for this case. I'm utilising an iterate method mapping (see also [custom methods](http://dozer.sourceforge.net/documentation/custommethods.html)) that ensures that the set will be instantiated as LinkedHashSet.